# Not able to add extraDataField in Eddystone-TLM

Tags: android, altbeacon

I am trying to add extraData for TLM but its not working. size of this field is coming 0 at receiver side. I have searched a lot but got nothing in response. Please help me out.

```
    byte[] urlBytes = new byte[0];
    try {
        urlBytes = UrlBeaconUrlCompressor.compress("http://www.google.com");
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    Identifier encodedUrlIdentifier = Identifier.fromBytes(urlBytes, 0, urlBytes.length, false);


    ArrayList<Identifier> identifiers = new ArrayList<Identifier>();
    identifiers.add(encodedUrlIdentifier);

    ArrayList<Long> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
    arrayList.add(Long.valueOf(et_temp.getText().toString()));
    arrayList.add(Long.valueOf(et_Voltage.getText().toString()));


    beacon = new Beacon.Builder()

            .setIdentifiers(identifiers)
            .setMultiFrameBeacon(true)
            .setBeaconTypeCode(0x20)
            .setManufacturer(0x20)
            .setServiceUuid(0xfeaa).setTxPower(-65)
            .setExtraDataFields(arrayList)

            .build();
    // i:4-13
    //"x,s:0-1=feaa,m:2-2=20,d:3-3,d:4-5,d:6-7,d:8-11,d:12-15"
    beaconParser.addExtraDataParser(new BeaconParser().setBeaconLayout(BeaconParser.EDDYSTONE_TLM_LAYOUT));


    beaconParser.setBeaconLayout(BeaconParser.EDDYSTONE_URL_LAYOUT);

    BeaconTransmitter beaconTransmitter = new BeaconTransmitter(this, beaconParser);
    beaconTransmitter.setConnectable(true);
    beaconTransmitter.startAdvertising(beacon);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that.  Eddystone-TLM is its own beacon transmission.  The whole concept of extra data fields is a feature of the parsing side of the library used to make it easy to access telemetry data from the corresponding main beacon object.  It does not apply to transmitting.

I am actually not 100% sure the library supports transmitting Eddystone-TLM, but you can try by setting it up independently from the Eddystone-URL transmission.